# How to create SignalR Groups at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, encryption, signalr

I'm starting to create an app and I'll use SignalR to make it work realtime. One of the things that the app is going to do is allow communication to just certain connected clients, only the ones that is part of some group.

As I saw in some exemples, I should make the client send a group name to the server and then it add the user connection id to a group, and then I'm able to send data only to the users that are in the same group as the connected client.

So my question is, imagine for example a school chat app, where I want only the Law students on one class to have access to the chat group of that class, so the GroupName I want to pass on the join group, should not be changed, and I want it to not be shown to some user that view the page source code, How would I do something that works like that ?

I thought on when rendering the Razor page, I get some info about the user and the group it belongs and create a encrypted key that would be decrypt on the server to add the user to the correct group, would it work ? But the problem is that a encrypted key would be the same for every connected user, as the input is always the same, right? It wouldn't  be a different key for each connection, so some could get the key and decrypt it...

So I wanted something that would be like a BCrypt Hash, that can generate different outputs for the same input, but I want to be able to reverse the key on the server to add the user on the correct group.

Any Idea of how would I do something like that ??

Comment: Are the users authenticated when using the chat? In that case the solution is straightforward, but I´m asking  just to confirm before actually answer the question

Comment: Yeah, they're kind authenticated. It's be something like, I scan a qrcode, and so I have access to a "room", and for each room there will be some sort of administrators, who will actually have to log in, and they will be able to communicate with the room's clients, and the other room's admins

Comment: And there should be an option where the admin could talk directly to one of the clients privately.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments:

> I scan a qrcode, and so I have access to a "room"

Assuming that the QR code has an implicit room id, when a user/client connects to the server you can map the connection id or username to a particular room id or signalr group name.

That map could be an static `ConcurrentDictionary` on the server.
But you are talking about encripting stuff. That looks to me that security is important. In that case, anyone who has access to the QR code could enter a room, and that´s not secure at all **unless you disable the QR access once the user has connected.**

If you really need to secure the room/group access, every user should be authenticated and persisted. Then the server knows exactly who is connecting and is able to asign a room (signalR group) automatically.

Comment: The qrcode is going to be generated by the admin and it should be valid for just some time, like 60seconds, and than, it should not be used to enter the room, but the user that used the qr to enter should not be disconnected, until the admin say it so.

Comment: I thought about something like, the user login with the code, and then I save it's access token to a database or something, and then it should be accessible till how admin revoke the access token. So when login on I should add the room Id and access "password" on the qr right. But how should I generate a different code every time, and still point it to the same room

Comment: The QR is generated by the server administrator, so the server can map the genarated code with a room id. In other words, there should be a relation between the QR code and the room id (just on the server). Then when a user uses that code to login, the server knows what room/group to join